# PhpStorm 2018.2, PHPUnit 5.7.27. Process finished with exit code 255

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

Using Laravel 5.3, PHP 5.6 and trying to test a package's class.

This is my test class

```
class OrderQuoteStrategyTest extends TestCase {

    public function testCanSendQuote() {
        $order=$this->createOrder();
        $orderSpec=new Orderspec();

        $this->expectException( \Exception::class);
        $this->expectExceptionMessage( 'Order must be waiting for Quote');

        $orderQuoteStrategy= new OrderQuoteStrategy();
        $orderQuoteStrategy->canSendQuote( $order, $orderSpec );
    }
}
```

Upon right click and 'Run OrderQuoteStrategyTest (PHPUnit)', I got the following error.

```
Process finished with exit code 255
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to post this Q&A style to help others in my situation.

On checking the php_error_log:

```
 PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in \vendor\doctrine\instantiator\src\Doctrine\Instantiator\Instantiator.php on line 95
```

Seems composer had updated 'doctrine/instantiator' to latest version which was compatible only with PHP 7.

For solution added this to require-dev :

```
  "doctrine/instantiator": "1.0.5"
```

and ran composer update.

Running the above test again worked without errors.